SSIS Get Sensitive Variable returning empty string
Using SSIS 2019 I have an SSIS package that has a sensitive project parameter set to true.
Using a Script Task with C# 2019 code, I am using the GetSensitiveValue().ToString() method.
I looked at several examples of this online, but no matter what I do it always returns an empty string.
If I set the project parameter sensitive property to false I see the string.
I tried using a variable dispenser and I tried using Dts.Variables, makes no difference, always returns an empty string.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Had to set the protection level of the project and every package to protect sensitive data, i.e. encryption level.
